# ADO.NET entity data model missing from Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using asp.net framework 4.6.1 and entity framework 6.1.3.

I created an empty webform and when I want to add ADO.NET Entity data model after going to the ADD -> New File -> Data, I can't see any option.

Going through the previous answers that were asked on the same, I tried so many things. Updated my entity framework from 6.1.2 to 6.1.3. Repaired my VS2015. But still it didn't get resolved:

[image]

Comment: Not a direct answer but WebForms and EDMX are both dropping in popularity fast. Are you sure you want to invest time in this?

Comment: I need to have the ADO.NET entity data model to update entities. @HenkHolterman

Comment: I don't think it's part of Community edition, but it's very hard to find information on this.